# How to find a spot inside circle

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I am trying to process image1 so that I can find the spot as shown in image2

image1:

[image]

image2:

[image]

the code that I am using mergers the spot with the outer circle... is there away to go around this?

```html
int thresh1 = 5;
Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;
vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;
pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));
pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());
Mat display_image = image.clone();
int ch[] = {0, 0};
    mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);
    Canny(gray0, gray, 0, thresh1, 5);
    //dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), Point(-1,-1));
    gray = gray0 >= (6)*255/11;
    //gray = gray0 >= (1)*255/11;
    //gray = gray0 >= (1)*255/11;
    //gray = gray0 >= (1)*255/11;
    imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo 2", gray );
    waitKey(0);
```

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: I want to locate the spot inside the circle

Comment: The white spot inside the gray circle ?

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. After find the circles, crop them.
2. Then resize using `cv2.INTER_CUBIC`(`cv2.INTER_NEAREST` is not good) .
3. Then threshold, and find contours on them again.
4. Use the `area ratio (contour's area / minEnclosingCircle's area) to filter`.

---

You can see the `#12` is so different with others(ratio is small). So we get it `#12`.

---

[image]

[image]